# CSS - adjust container width

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm making a few changes to a site and want to change the width of the container to go across the whole page. I'm a bit of a noob so not sure if I've don't it correctly, but want the width to be 3000px. I have the option of container id and container class. So basically what CSS do I put in which box?
The theme  I am using is Porto by Spyropress. But looking for some CSS help:) 
Thank you very much!!

Comment: You want width to be stretched till 3000px or full-screen? In case for full-screen use width:100%. Some thing like this : #your-container-id{ width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS style page (or code) where you have the container, you should write the following line:

```
width:3000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward answer would be to use the style="width: 3000px;" definition instead of the id or the class (even if it is not a really clean choice).

If you have no chance to add a style and you have called a CSS, you can do it by id or by class, depends on how often you will have Elements with 3000px width (single time go for id, multiple times go for class). In general classes and id link the parts in your CSS with your html definitions (named-links). They do not serve you with direct CSS, this is done by the style="" Element.

Some Code:

```
#some_id {
width: 3000px;
}

.some_class {
width: 3000px;
}
```

And some additional info about general css (because it is much more than just id's and classes if I think about the cascading part): http://www.cssbasics.com/